# How to render a TemplateResponse in a Django unittest

Tags: python, django, unicode

I'm attempting to check the body of a response inside a Django unittest for sepcific text, by doing:

```
response = client.post('/path/to/form', form_data)
self.assertTrue('some text' in unicode(response, 'utf-8', 'ignore'))
```

However, I get the error:

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, TemplateResponse found
```

If I replace `unicode()` with `str()` it works fine, but that prevents me from looking for Unicode text. Why can't a TemplateResponse be casted to unicode like it can be for str?

Answer (score 2):

Use `self.assertContains(response, 'some text')`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the body of a response, then the typical  approach is to use `response.content`, rather than trying to call `unicode(response)`.